# Amazon Web Service Wordpress Plugin cURL Error

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, aws

I am having trouble activating a [wordpress plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-web-services/).

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
>
> The official Amazon Web Services SDK requires PHP 5.3.3+ and cURL 7.16.2+ compiled with OpenSSL and zlib. Your server currently has no PHP cURL library activated.

I am on Ubuntu LAMP stack, I have checked that cURL is installed -

`php -v` outputs

```
PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) (built: May 22 2017 13:29:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
```

`curl -V` outputs

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`